# Want to run a .net framework 4.x or 3.x client against a asp.net core 2.0 signalr service. possible?

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Want to run a .net framework 4.x or 3.x client against a asp.net core 2.0 signalr service. possible?

for now my client is a .net framework 4.x or 3.x console app.
eventually it will be a DLL i drop into unity3d plugins directory.

Then i can call my methods like so MyNet4ClientClass.MakeSignalrCoreCall(data).

Is this possible? Can .NET 3.x or 4.x talk to asp.net core 2.0 signalr service?

I tried to add the nuget package for Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-alpha2-final but....

"Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR 1.0.0-alpha2-final'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author. 0   "

i thought this post was hopeful
https://www.rizamarhaban.com/2016/09/13/asp-net-core-signalr-for-windows-10-uwp-app/

in the post the guy talks to signalr code 2.0 from a UWP app
the client UWP app uses "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client": "2.2.1" from nuget

and service which uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server: 0.2.0-alpha1-22118
obtained from https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json repository

this works its seems because these older SignalR.Server packages still exposes themselves the old signalr way. you can see from the url it exposes at /signalr/hubs

but the new new signalr core changed its protocol sometime so now incompatible.

how can i talk to the new new signalr core from .net framework 4.x or 3.x client ?

Comment: I think you can't because the interface changed.

Comment: The SignalR Core client targets netstandard2.0 so you should be able to make it run on .NET Framework 4.6.1. Anything lower than that will most likely not work. Anything lower than .NET Framework 4.5 will not work for sure.